# .NET Core Entity Framework get user running Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API running which is running under Windows Authentication. I have Entity Framework for working with my database using connectionstring syntax:

```
"data source=dbserver;initial catalog=IntranetDB;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

My Web API is running under a specific application pool and service account: `sa_db`.

This `sa_db` is owner of the database and has `bulk load` enabled.

One process in the API is savind a `.csv` file to a network share and then calls the SP to open this file and do something with it.

**Problem**

We got some issues about permissions ( Access Denied ), after some changes like adding the following to the SP:

```
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
```

we got the exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.
```

But the `sa_db` has this enabled.

When we added the security group of the AD Users using the API to the SQL Database with `bulk load` enabled, everything worked.

Looking in the Activity Montitor of the SQL I only see the `sa_db` account.

Why is the SP running under the AD User using the API and not the service account?

Comment: `But the sa_db has this enabled` - but is `sa_db` the [owner](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33551/5203) of the procedure?

Comment: Wow ok! Is indeed another user!! I manually runned scripts under my account. Thanks!!

Comment: @GSerg: move this into an answer so the owner can mark it as correct.